# Ubuntu 14.04 LTS can't resolve DNS

Tags: 14.04, networking, dns

When I do `ping google.com` I get `ping: unknown host google.com`

But when do `ping 173.194.67.138` I get this:

```
PING 173.194.67.138 (173.194.67.138) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 173.194.67.138: icmp_seq=1 ttl=48 time=5.33 ms
64 bytes from 173.194.67.138: icmp_seq=2 ttl=48 time=5.40 ms
```

So there must be an error when it is trying to resolve the DNS, is there anything I can do?

This is from my syslog:

```
    Aug 14 19:55:15 localhost ntpd[1184]: ntpd 4.2.6p5@1.2349-o Mon Apr 13 13:39:46 UTC 2015 (1)
Aug 14 19:55:15 localhost ntpd[1185]: proto: precision = 0.102 usec
Aug 14 19:55:15 localhost ntpd[1185]: ntp_io: estimated max descriptors: 1024, initial socket boundary: 16
Aug 14 19:55:15 localhost ntpd[1185]: Listen and drop on 0 v4wildcard 0.0.0.0 UDP 123
Aug 14 19:55:15 localhost ntpd[1185]: Listen and drop on 1 v6wildcard :: UDP 123
Aug 14 19:55:15 localhost ntpd[1185]: Listen normally on 2 lo 127.0.0.1 UDP 123
Aug 14 19:55:15 localhost ntpd[1185]: Listen normally on 3 eth0 108.61.209.172 UDP 123
Aug 14 19:55:15 localhost ntpd[1185]: Listen normally on 4 lo ::1 UDP 123
Aug 14 19:55:15 localhost ntpd[1185]: Listen normally on 5 eth0 fe80::5400:ff:fe10:937 UDP 123
Aug 14 19:55:15 localhost ntpd[1185]: peers refreshed
Aug 14 19:55:15 localhost ntpd[1185]: Listening on routing socket on fd #22 for interface updates
Aug 14 19:55:19 localhost ntpd[1185]: ntpd exiting on signal 15
Aug 14 19:55:29 localhost ntpdate[1216]: Can't find host 1.time.constant.com: Name or service not known (-2)
Aug 14 19:55:39 localhost ntpdate[1216]: Can't find host 2.time.constant.com: Name or service not known (-2)
Aug 14 19:55:49 localhost ntpdate[1216]: Can't find host 3.time.constant.com: Name or service not known (-2)
Aug 14 19:55:49 localhost ntpdate[1216]: no servers can be used, exiting
Aug 14 19:55:49 localhost ntpd[1250]: ntpd 4.2.6p5@1.2349-o Mon Apr 13 13:39:46 UTC 2015 (1)
Aug 14 19:55:49 localhost ntpd[1251]: proto: precision = 0.122 usec
Aug 14 19:55:49 localhost ntpd[1251]: ntp_io: estimated max descriptors: 1024, initial socket boundary: 16
Aug 14 19:55:49 localhost ntpd[1251]: Listen and drop on 0 v4wildcard 0.0.0.0 UDP 123
Aug 14 19:55:49 localhost ntpd[1251]: Listen and drop on 1 v6wildcard :: UDP 123
Aug 14 19:55:49 localhost ntpd[1251]: Listen normally on 2 lo 127.0.0.1 UDP 123
Aug 14 19:55:49 localhost ntpd[1251]: Listen normally on 3 eth0 108.61.209.172 UDP 123
Aug 14 19:55:49 localhost ntpd[1251]: Listen normally on 4 lo ::1 UDP 123
Aug 14 19:55:49 localhost ntpd[1251]: Listen normally on 5 eth0 fe80::5400:ff:fe10:937 UDP 123
Aug 14 19:55:49 localhost ntpd[1251]: peers refreshed
Aug 14 19:55:49 localhost ntpd[1251]: Listening on routing socket on fd #22 for interface updates
Aug 14 19:55:59 localhost ntpd[1251]: Deferring DNS for 1.time.constant.com 1
Aug 14 19:56:09 localhost ntpd[1251]: Deferring DNS for 2.time.constant.com 1
Aug 14 19:56:19 localhost ntpd[1251]: Deferring DNS for 3.time.constant.com 1
Aug 14 19:56:19 localhost ntpd[1255]: signal_no_reset: signal 17 had flags 4000000
Aug 14 19:56:31 localhost ntpd_intres[1255]: host name not found: 1.time.constant.com
Aug 14 19:56:41 localhost ntpd_intres[1255]: host name not found: 2.time.constant.com
Aug 14 19:56:51 localhost ntpd_intres[1255]: host name not found: 3.time.constant.com
```

Comment: Your `syslog` blob just shows the Network Time Protocol Daemon burbling, but does contain a single piece of information. `Can't find host 1.time.constant.com: Name or service not known (-2)`. Why post the whole blob without reading it?

Comment: because i don't now what it's saying

Comment: Use `grep dnsmasq /var/log/syslog*|less` to see more interesting messages.

Comment: `Date/Time`  `hostname` `processname[PID]:` `message generated by syslog(3)`. See `man 3 syslog`.

Answer (score 7):

I'll bet you can't do this:

```
nslookup rtfm.mit.edu
```

but you can do this:

```
nslookup rtfm.mit.edu 8.8.8.8
```

If you check the content of your `/etc/resolv.conf` file, it's probably empty, or pointing your DNS resolver to something your Ubuntu can't reach.  `/etc/resolv.conf` can be configured manually with any plain text editor (vim, nano, etc), or from `/etc/network/interfaces` if you have the `resolvconf` package installed.  Alternatively, Network Manager can manage it and will acquire DNS server information from DHCP, if your environment is using that. You'll need to figure out which method your Ubuntu is using, because changes made manually to correct `/etc/resolv.conf` will get overwritten by `resolvconf` the next time you reboot or disconnect from your network, and Network Manager likes to scribble all over the place.

You don't say if this is an office machine using ethernet, a home machine with wifi, a desktop, or a laptop, and what sort of network connection it has.  I'd need more information about those details to be more specific.  Specific answers will need more details from you.

Comment: it's a vps server on vultr.com. you are right  i can only do the second command. my /etc/resolv.conf has nameserver 108.61.10.10
nameserver 2001:19f0:300:1704::6

Comment: i added dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4 to /etc/network/interfaces and in seems to be working now, is this the correct way or should i be looking for the appropriate dns used by vultr by default?

Comment: If the software you are running on VPS is not constantly doing DNS requests, then google nameservers are good enough. Otherwise, vultr native nameservers may perform faster (you should test).

Comment: Normally, if your hosting company provides a DNS server, and you find you can't resolve DNS names, ping the IP of their DNS server from your host and see if it can be reached.   Try traceroute if ping doesn't work, then contact vultr.com's tech support for help, because it looks like a basic issue with their DNS server and/or routes between your host and their DNS server, which is all detail configuration they would know and no one here would.  The google DNS you added is being used as a fall-back DNS server when your primary DNS server isn't responding.

Comment: And this really isn't just an Ubuntu issue, server fault was the correct forum to begin with.